# Error: Cannot find module 'is-property' AWS Lambda Nforce Salesforce

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, salesforce

My `Node.js` code works fine locally, but when i am uploading on `AWS lambda` function i'm getting following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'is-property'

```
**I have tried 
 exports.handler = function (event,context) 
 exports.handler = function (event,context,callback)  
 exports.handler = function (event)**
```

Unable to add a photo of folder structure. Please click following link for the folder structure

[Click for the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwkbK.png)

Index.js

```
var CLIENT_ID = '**************************';
var CLIENT_SECRET = '*******************************';
var USERNAME = '**************';
var PASSWORD = '*********';
var CALLBACK_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/_callback';
var SECURITY_TOKEN = '***************************************';

var nforce = require('nforce');
exports.handler = function (event, context,callback) {

    var newCase = nforce.createSObject('Case');
    newCase.set('Device_Id__c', event.serialNumber);
    newCase.set('Button_Press_Type__c', event.clickType);
    newCase.set('Button_Notes__c', ' AWS Dash button Id: 34254555 Click Type: clickType');

    if(event.clickType  == 'Long'){
        newCase.set('Priority', 'High');
        newCase.set('Subject', 'High |'+  event.clickType +' | ' + event.serialNumber);
    }
    if(event.clickType  == 'Double')    {
        newCase.set('Priority', 'Medium');
        newCase.set('Subject', 'Medium |'+  event.clickType +' | ' + event.serialNumber);
    }
    if(event.clickType  == 'Single')    {
        newCase.set('Priority', 'Medium');
        newCase.set('Subject', 'Medium |'+  event.clickType +' | ' + event.serialNumber);
    }

    var org = nforce.createConnection({
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirectUri: CALLBACK_URL,
        environment: 'production', 
        mode: 'single'
      });

      org.authenticate({ username: USERNAME, password: PASSWORD, }, function(err, resp){
         // store the oauth object for this user
         if(!err){ 
            //var oauth = resp;
            console.log('Cached Token: ' + org.message);
            org.insert({ sobject: newCase }, function(err, resp){
                if(!err) console.log('It worked! ==> ' + resp);
                else console.log('Error ===> ' + err);
              }); 

            } else {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(resp));
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
            }
    });
};
```

Comment: Are your node modules pushed to the bucket holding your code?

Comment: Yeah, i think so. My zip has node_modules folder and index.js. I am new to node js and aws so i may be missing something.

Comment: Can you verify the contents in the storage bucket and possibly include a screenshot here? Can you also include how you're importing your dependencies? I.e. code that looks like `const dependency = require('dependency');`

Comment: Dependencies in package,json looks like this **"dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^2.3.11",
    "faye": "1.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.1",
    "lodash": "2.4.1",
    "mime": "1.2.11",
    "request": "^2.49.0"
  }, "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.0.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.0.1",
    "express": "4.1.1",
    "express-session": "1.0.4",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.9.0",
    "jade": "1.3.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "mocha": "1.18.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "should": "3.3.1"
  }**

Comment: Can you share your whole index.js file? Also can you verify the contents in your uploaded storage bucket?

Comment: Unable to add index.js to comments so added up in the description. I have also uploaded screenshot of the folder structure. I am using nforce js library https://www.npmjs.com/package/nforce

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled nforce library in a folder and placed index.js in the folder. Zipped and uploaded to AWS and worked. Looks like it had something to do with nforce installation.